Overlapping of parent over child
I am trying to create a floating menu. Therefore I would like a parent element to overlap its child. I've researched that a z-index of -1 on the child and auto on the parent should work. The elements are both positioned absolute.
The blue rectangular children should pop out of the circular red parents. To not hide the circle, the child must slide out from below.
However in my code it does not work.
Could you point me in the right direction what I am doing wrong?
HTML:
<div id="floating-button" class="show">
    <div id="main-button">
      ...
    </div>
    <div id="contact-button" class="action-button show animate">
      <div class="extended show"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="support-button" class="action-button show">
      <div class="extended show"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="newsletter-button" class="action-button show">
      <div class="extended show"></div>
    </div>
</div>

SCSS:
@mixin button {
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 40px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: scale .3s;
  
  &.show {
    display: block;
  }
  
  &.animate {
    scale: 1;
  }
}

#floating-button {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 40px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  
  &.show {
    height: 380px;
  }
  
  #main-button {
    @include button;
    
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
  }
  
  .action-button {
    @include button;
    display: none;
    scale: 0;
    z-index: auto;
    
    .extended {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 16px;
      right: 40px;
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      z-index: -1;
      transition: width .3s;
      border-top-left-radius: 10px;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
      
      &.show {
        width: 240px;
        height: 46px;
        background-color: blue;
      }
    }
  }
  
  #contact-button {
    bottom: 100px;
    right: 0px;
  }
  
  #support-button {
    bottom: 200px;
    right: 0px;
  }
  
  #newsletter-button {
    bottom: 300px;
    right: 0px;
  }
}

Here's the codepen version of what I am trying to do - you can ignore the JavaScript.
https://codepen.io/Manuel-Simon-the-bold/pen/oNKwoWW

Can you update this codepen with a [MRE] and also maybe include an example of what you're trying to do (just with mspaint or something) to give a better idea of what needs to change?

I see the buttons are absolutely positioned, but there isn't a "relative" class applied anywhere. When you use absolute positioning, you need "relative" applied to the element the absolutely positioned item(s) is(are) referring to for its(their) placement. This may not be what is causing your problem, but it's also a quick fix.

I got a position: fixed in the otuer container. CodePen Link added. The blue rectangle should be overlapped by the red circle.

read the accepted answer of the duplicate until the end (I insist on the end)

Thank you, in case you were refering to the elements that create their own stacking contexts. removing the scale property solved it!

You could use a 3d transform to 'tuck' the element under its parent.
Set transform-style: preserve-3d on the parent
and for .show don't bother with z-index but set
transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, -1px);

